# read file and splitting it's content when finding a delimiter

Tags: java

the content of my file is the following :

```
nellkb:company_dc
  rdfs:label "dC"  "WASHINGTON" , "Washington" ;
  skos:prefLabel "www.wikipedia.com" .
nellkb:politicsblog_quami_ekta
  rdfs:label "Quami Ekta" ;
  skos:prefLabel "Quami Ekta" .
nellkb:female_ramendra_kumar
  rdfs:label "Ramendra Kumar" ;
  skos:prefLabel "Ramendra Kumar" .
```

i need to split my file at the delimiter '.' and save what we have before it in a string. How can i do that ? i tried the following but it does not work

```
try {
    String sCurrentLine = null;
    int i = 0;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rdfInstanceFile));
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        splitted = sCurrentLine.split(".");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you set that as a delimiter on the `Scanner` object?

Comment: Not sure what `splitted` is, but on every iteration in your `while` loop its value will get replaced. If this is unwanted, consider using an `ArrayList<String>` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

USE the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. This scenario is perfect for it. All you need to do is specify the `'\\.'` delimiter.

There is no need to build a string AND THEN split it...

```java
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InputStream is = ScanFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/foo.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);
            scan.useDelimiter("\\.[\r\n]+"); // Tokenize at dots (.) followed by CR/LF.
            
            int i = 1;
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                String line = scan.next().trim();
                
                System.out.printf("Line #%d%n-------%n%n%s%n%n", i++, line);
            }
            
            scan.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Line #1
-------

nellkb:company_dc
  rdfs:label "dC"  "WASHINGTON" , "Washington" ;
  skos:prefLabel "WASHINGTON"

Line #2
-------

nellkb:politicsblog_quami_ekta
  rdfs:label "Quami Ekta" ;
  skos:prefLabel "Quami Ekta"

Line #3
-------

nellkb:female_ramendra_kumar
  rdfs:label "Ramendra Kumar" ;
  skos:prefLabel "Ramendra Kumar"
```

---

## Additional Information

> #### [useDelimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern))
>
> `public Scanner useDelimiter(String pattern)`
>
> Sets this scanner's delimiting pattern to a pattern constructed from the specified `String`.
>
> An invocation of this method of the form `useDelimiter(pattern)` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation `useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(pattern)`).
>
> Invoking the `reset()` method will set the scanner's delimiter to the default.
>
> **Parameters**:
>    `pattern` - A string specifying a delimiting pattern
> **Returns**:
>    this scanner

The `Scanner` constructor takes six (6) different types of objects: `File`, `InputStream`, `Path`, `Readable`, `ReadableByteChannel`, and `String`.

```
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.
Scanner(File source)
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.
Scanner(File source, String charsetName)
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream.
Scanner(InputStream source)
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream.
Scanner(InputStream source, String charsetName)
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.
Scanner(Path source)
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.
Scanner(Path source, String charsetName)
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified source.
Scanner(Readable source)
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified channel.
Scanner(ReadableByteChannel source)
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified channel.
Scanner(ReadableByteChannel source, String charsetName)
// Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.
Scanner(String source)
```

---

### Advanced Solution

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanFile {
    private static ClassLoader loader = ScanFile.class.getClassLoader();
    
    private static interface LineProcessor {
        void process(String line);
    }

    private static interface Reader<T> {
        T read(String resource, String delimiter) throws IOException;
        void flush();
    }

    private abstract static class FileScanner<T> implements Reader<T> {
        private LineProcessor processor;
        public void setProcessor(LineProcessor processor) {
            this.processor = processor;
        }

        public T read(Scanner scan, String delimiter, boolean close) throws IOException {
            scan.useDelimiter(delimiter);
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                processor.process(scan.next().trim());
            }
            if (close) {
                scan.close();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public T read(InputStream is, String delimiter, boolean close) throws IOException {
            T t = read(new Scanner(is), delimiter, true);
            if (close) {
                is.close();
            }
            return t;
        }

        public T read(String resource, String delimiter) throws IOException {
            return read(loader.getResourceAsStream("resources/" + resource), delimiter, true);
        }
    }
    
    public static class FileTokenizer extends FileScanner<List<String>> {
        private List<String> tokens;
        public List<String> getTokens() {
            return tokens;
        }
        public FileTokenizer() {
            super();
            tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
            setProcessor(new LineProcessor() {
                @Override
                public void process(String token) {
                    tokens.add(token);
                }
            });
        }
        public List<String> read(Scanner scan, String delimiter, boolean close) throws IOException {
            super.read(scan, delimiter, close);
            return tokens;
        }
        @Override
        public void flush() {
            tokens.clear();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileTokenizer scanner = new FileTokenizer();
            List<String> items = scanner.read("foo.txt", "\\.[\r\n]+");

            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                System.out.printf("Line #%d%n-------%n%n%s%n%n", i + 1, items.get(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked. Howerver, in my file i can have data as sources like "www.google.com". In that case, what do we use in the useDelimiter ?

Comment: If we want to store these data to use it afterwards, what would we use ? (not an Arraylist i guess ? )

Comment: Store the lines in a list of type String

Comment: Great ! Thanks again !!

Comment: if only there was a way to put gold stars instead of just up-vote by 1

Answer (score 2):

First read the contents of the file into a string, split the string and save it in a string array.

```
try {
        String sCurrentLine = "";
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        String splitted[]= null;
        int i = 0;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rdfInstanceFile));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(sCurrentLine) ;
        }
       splitted = content.toString().split("\\.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `splitted = content.split(".");` will not work..try once

Comment: You should use `StringBuilder` instead of String concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
splitted = sCurrentLine.split(".");
```

with

```
splitted = sCurrentLine.split("\\.");
```

**EDIT**

```
String sCurrentLine = null;
int i = 0;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rdfInstanceFile));
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    content.append(sCurrentLine);
}
splitted = content.toString().split("\\.");
```

It'll work.

Comment: It won't work - he is using readLine, but he needs to get 3 lines together in the output. Entire approach is broken.

Comment: What about when we have a source data in the file such as "www.google.fr" ? Thanks

Comment: your file name is `www.google.fr` or you have to fetch it from link [www.google.fr](http://www.google.fr)??